# how to have children thread synchronize with main thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, .net-4.5, async-await

i have below code, looks like the await statement in ApiClass will cause function "AControllerMethodInAspMVC" to return earlier before each api.GetResultFromAnotherService is finished.

the main thread return before all children thread finished. is there a way to fix this issue?

```
        private ApiClass api = new ApiClass();

        [HttpPost]
        public Task<JsonResult> AControllerMethodInAspMVC()
        {
            var arrayOfItem =  …; 

           List<object> resultObjs = new List<object>();
            var resultLock = new SemaphoreSlim(1);

            Parallel.ForEach(
                arrayOfItem,
                async item =>
                {
                    var result = await api.GetResultFromAnotherService(item.id);

                    var resultObj = new {
                    // prepare resultObj from result
                    };
                    await resultLock.WaitAsync();
                    resultObjs.add(resultObj);
                    resultLock.Release();
                });

            return Task.FromResult(this.Json(resultObjs));
        }



Public class ApiClass
{
       Public async Task<string> GetResultFromAnotherService(string id)
       {
               ….
               …
               await Call AnAsyncOperationToGetResult   
              …
              …
       }
}
```

Comment: @M.Babcock i am not sure i understand what you mean. this is a very common usage. you can assume ApiClass is an wrapper on top of HttpClient, and you need to fire parallel request to get some information from another web service .

to fix my problem is easy. change GetResultFromAnotherService to not return a task. but this will end up blocking the thread.  which is not i want.

Comment: @shrimpy: Based on your example, I strongly suspect that you do not have [`targetFramework` set to `4.5` in your app.config](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/11/19/all-about-httpruntime-targetframework.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Parallel.ForEach()` does not understand `async`, so your lambda is compiled as `async void`. What this means is that as soon as you hit the `await`, the `ForEach()` thinks the iteration is complete and continues with another iteration.

One way to fix that would be to first start all of the service calls at the same time and then wait for all of them to complete using `Task.WhenAll()`:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> AControllerMethodInAspMVC()
{
    var arrayOfItem =  …; 

    var tasks = arrayOfItem.Select(
        item => api.GetResultFromAnotherService(item.id));

    return await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

If you want to limit how many times is the service call executed in parallel, you could use `SemaphoreSlim`'s `WaitAsync()`:

```
var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(degreeOfParallelism);

var tasks = arrayOfItem.Select(
    async item =>
    {
        await semaphore.WaitAsync();

        try
        {
            return await api.GetResultFromAnotherService(item.id);
        }
        finally
        {
            sempahore.Release();
        }
    });
```